# KeyError when trying to import simplistic custom package - Seemingly Inconsistent

Tags: import, package, keyerror

I'm working through the python institute module on packages and I'm getting an error when trying to import modules, but only in specific cases. The folder structure is visible in the photo attached. :

*C:\Users\Luke\py\packages*

[Folder Pathway](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zEasA.png)

When trying to run the following code (to import specific modules and run the functions within):

```
from sys import path

path.append('..\\packages')

import extra.good.best.sigma
from extra.good.best.tau import FunT

print(extra.good.best.sigma.FunS())
print(FunT())
```

I get the error message: "KeyError: 'extra'"

However when running the following code, it works without issue:

```
from sys import path
path.append('..\\packages')

import extra.iota
print(extra.iota.FunI())
```

NOTE - The various modules themselves are exactly the same, the only distinction is they return  its own specific module name, for instance the Iota module code is:

```
def FunI():
    return "Iota"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    print("I prefer to be a module")
```

Is anyone able to spot what difference is causing the error or has suggestions for debugging? I'm still fairly new to coding so any help would be really appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: which is the line raising `KeyError: 'extra'` ? This error is raised when one tryes to access a value stored in a key of a dictionary that does not have that key. Try to detect which is the dictionary you are trying to access and that does not have the key `'extra'`.

Comment: In the console it provides the following error message: * File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 1099, in _get_parent_path

KeyError: 'extra' *   - I've looked for similar error messages on this site and most people report the issue being that an __innit__.py file required in the destination folder but this doesn't seem to have helped mine to work. I'm not actually able to decipher the error message either to locate the dictionary in question so I'm a bit stumped

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem, also with the same example within the python institute training module.

What I found is that if I run main2.py directly via python3 it works fine.  Where I experience the same error as you is when main2.py runs in the IPython shell within Spyder.

To get it working in Spyder, I had to add an **init**.py to each subfolder in my folder hierarchy of "extra", then right click on the IPython shell to quit it, and let Spyder launch a fresh shell. At which point Spyder could run main2.py successfully.